# support for vsi7z (direct reading of compressed 7z files) in terra and sf?

Tags: version, gdal, r-sf, 7zip, terra

The current versions of `terra` and `sf` do not support direct reading of `7zip` compressed files, because `GDAL` does not support it yet. But it seems that this feature will be included in `GDAL` version 3.7.0, scheduled for May 1, 2023 (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/milestone/42). Knowing that `terra` and `sf` are currently using `GDAL` version 3.4.1, released on 12/27/2021, should we expect that support for direct reading of `7zip` files will be available in `terra`'s or `sf`'s `CRAN` binary packages a year or so after its inclusion in `GDAL`? I have no idea how `GDAL` is integrated with `terra` or `sf`, so my question may be naive or poorly phrased. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your operating system, and how you install.

On Windows we depend on what is included in Rtools. Rtools tends to be up-to-date. I would expect a delay in the order of months. But as you point out it more than 12 months now. Rtools was just updated to GDAL 3.6.0 (and it should be updated again soon as that version of GDAL was retracted). There can be an additional delay if a new version of Rtools is not yet used at CRAN (or only for R-devel), so it can sometimes help to install from source.

On Linux you can install any version of GDAL you want, if you have permission to do so. The defaults on some Linux systems are terribly old. On Ubuntu it helps a lot to use the `ubuntugis-unstable` repository (see [instructions](https://github.com/rspatial/terra)). If you are on Ubuntu and use [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/), then it depends on what they use.

On OSX you may use the CRAN binary or GDAL install yourself from source or install it with "brew". You can see what is used for CRAN [here](https://github.com/R-macos/recipes/tree/master/recipes). I think the lag in the GDAL version of the CRAN binaries typically is also only in the order of months. "brew" seems to keep very good track of GDAL updates.

---

Update now that the CRAN windows version is using GDAL 3.7.2.

https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html states that for `/vsi7z/` to work GDAL must be

> built against libarchive (and libarchive having LZMA support to be of practical use).

I do not think that is the case for the CRAN build on windows; so it won't work there unless a change is made to the RTools compilation chain for GDAL.

Answer (score 0):

`terra 1.7.71` relies on `gdal 3.7.2`, which is now supposed to support direct reading of `7zip` compressed files.

So, to read a raster in a `7zip` file, I tried the syntax indicated by https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html:
"To point to a file inside a `7z` file, the filename must be of the form `/vsi7z/path/to/the/file.7z/path/inside/the/7z/file`, where `path/to/the/file.7z` is relative or absolute and `path/inside/the/7z/file` is the relative path to the file inside the archive."

Such as:

```
rast("/vsi7z/MyZIP.7z/MyRast.tif")
```

However, it failed. Is `vsi7z` supported by `terra 1.7.71`? If so, is there an example of the syntax to use? Thank you very much!